# Tengo una tabla, se cortan las filas y no se visualizan en la ventana porque se hizo mas grande que la pantalla de mi pc

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen día a todos!!!
Estoy detenido en mi programa, resulta que tengo una tabla con `Treeview`, y la coloco en una ventana donde aparecen los datos pero la ventana que los contiene se hace mucho mas grande que la pantalla de mi computadora cortando las filas las cuales ya no puedo ver los datos que siguen, limité el tamaño de mi pantalla para que no se haga mas grande, después le puse un `Scrollbar` pero no funcionó, solo hace el recorrido hasta el dato que se alcanza a ver en la pantalla de mi computadora, la única solución que tengo es mover la tabla de lugar donde si cabe completa pero en el futuro se llenara de datos y volveré a tener el mismo problema, alguien sabe como se pueden visualizar las filas faltantes????

Anexo mi código para que me ayuden con una explicación mas gráfica

```
    columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3')
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tab2, show='headings', height=30, columns=columns)
    self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    self.tree.column("#1", width=450, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
    self.tree.column("#2", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
    self.tree.column("#3", width=80, minwidth=20)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text='Estudio', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#2', text='Costo', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#3', text='Maquila', anchor=tk.CENTER)

    self.get_estudios()

   def run_query_1(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_lab) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
    # Consulta de datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM price_list ORDER BY id_folio DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query_1(query)

 # Filling the Rows
def get_estudios(self):

   # Limpiando la tabla
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    # getting data
    query = 'SELECT * FROM price_list ORDER BY id_folio DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query_1(query).fetchall()
    print(len(db_rows))
    h = int(len(db_rows))
    # filling data
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = (row[1], row[2], row[3])) # aqui es donde se debe de ajustar el scrollbar y que la tabla no se pierda verdad????

    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab2, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
    vsb.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = N + S)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand = vsb.set)
```

Agradezco su tiempo amigos!!!!

En la imagen se ve como se cortó mi fila :( y aun faltan mas filas por recorrer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Edición

Anexando otra duda:
Se esta intentando colocar un scrollbar de manera horizontal en el cual inicialmente solo aparece el scrollbar pero no funciona, nuestro amigo @FJSevilla me ayudo con un ejemplo basico a lo cual lo reproduje de manera independiente anexando lo que quiero que se muestre en la tabla y se pudo realizar despues intente añadirlo a mi programa principal pero me da el mismo resultado, realizando algunas modificaciones consegui que se desplazara el scrollbar pero ahora la tabla se ve mucho mas pequeña, alguna sugerencia o que fue lo que omiti para que no se este dando el mismo resultado???

```
        #Pestañas
        self._tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self.wind)
        self._tab_control.grid(row= 1, column = 0) 
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self._tab_control) 
        self._tab_control.add(self.tab2, text="Pacientes", compound=tk.TOP
        columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6', '#7', '#8', '#9', '#10', '#11', '#12', '#13', '#14', '#15', '#16', '#17', '#18', '#19')
        self.tree2 = ttk.Treeview(self.tab2, show='headings', height=3, columns=columns)
        self.tree2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.tab2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.tab2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use("classic")

        self.tree2.column("#1", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree2.column("#2", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree2.column("#3", width=400, minwidth=200)
        self.tree2.column("#4", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree2.column("#5", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree2.column("#6", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree2.column("#7", width=300) # Prueba Clinica 1
        self.tree2.column("#8", width=300) # Prueba Clinica 2
        self.tree2.column("#9", width=300) # Prueba Clinica 3
        self.tree2.column("#10", width=300) # Prueba Clinica 4
        self.tree2.column("#11", width=300) # Prueba Clinica 5
        self.tree2.column("#12", width=200) # Fecha de estudio
        self.tree2.column("#13", width=200) # Fecha de entrega
        self.tree2.column("#14", width=150) # Atendido
        self.tree2.column("#15", width=150) # Promocion
        self.tree2.column("#16", width=150) #Subtotal
        self.tree2.column("#17", width=150) # Anticipo
        self.tree2.column("#18", width=150) # Total
        self.tree2.column("#19", width=150) # Saldo a pagar

        self.tree2.heading('#1', text='Folio', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#2', text='Nombre', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#3', text='Dirección', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#4', text='Teléfono', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#5', text='Edad', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#6', text='Sexo', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#7', text='Prueba Clinica 1', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#8', text='Prueba Clinica 2', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#9', text='Prueba Clinica 3', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#10', text='Prueba Clinica 4', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#11', text='Prueba Clinica 5', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#12', text='Fecha de estudio', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#13', text='Fecha de entrega', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#14', text='Atendido', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#15', text='Promoción', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#16', text='Subtotal', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#17', text='Anticipo', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#18', text='Total', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree2.heading('#19', text='Saldo a pagar', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        #for idx in range(100):
        #    self.tree2.insert("", idx, text="", values=([str(idx)] * 6))
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self._tab_control, orient="vertical", command=self.tree2.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
        self.tree2.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self._tab_control, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree2.xview)
        hsb.grid(row = 2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = tk.W+tk.E)
        self.tree2.configure(xscrollcommand = hsb.set)
        self.get_pacients()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el código que muestras el único problema que veo es que tu ScrollBar por defecto ocupa el centro de la celda, sin usar todo el alto del padre haciéndola de hecho inútil. Para solventarlo solo debes usar el argumento `sticky` de `grid` y forzar a que se alinee de "norte" a "sur" (`sticky="ns"`):

Un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.note_book = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.note_book.pack()
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.note_book) 

        self.note_book.add(self.tab2, text="Tab Dos", compound=tk.TOP)
        columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tab2, show='headings', height=30, columns=columns)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.tab2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.tree.column("#1", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#2", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#3", width=400, minwidth=200)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Estudio', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Costo', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#3', text='Maquila', anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for idx in range(100):
            self.tree.insert("", idx, text="", values=([str(idx)] * 3))

        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab2, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainFrame(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

### Edición

el procedimiento para agregar una barra horizontal es el mismo, solo que usaremos `TreeView.xview` y el argumento `xscrollcommand`. También es importante asegurarse de que la barra de Scroll ocupa exactamente las mismas columnas que el TreeView (`column` y `columnspan` deben ser lo mismo)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.note_book = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.note_book.pack()
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.note_book) 

        self.note_book.add(self.tab2, text="Tab Dos", compound=tk.TOP)
        columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.tab2, show='headings', height=30, columns=columns)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)
        self.tab2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tab2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.tree.column("#1", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#2", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#3", width=400, minwidth=200)
        self.tree.column("#4", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#5", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#6", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Estudio', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Costo', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#3', text='Maquila', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#4', text='Aaaaaaa', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#5', text='Bbbbbbb', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#6', text='Ccccccc', anchor=tk.CENTER)

        for idx in range(100):
            self.tree.insert("", idx, text="", values=([str(idx)] * 6))

        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab2, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab2, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        hsb.grid(row = 1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = tk.W+tk.E)
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand = hsb.set)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    MainFrame(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo JFSevilla siempre echandome una mano!!!! copie y pegue el codigo que me proporcionaste en otro nuevo *.py y en efecto funcionó!!!! trate de tomarlo y colocarlo en mi codigo original y desgraciadamente no me daba T_T cambio el tamaño del scrollbar que agradezco tu comentario de hecho no sabia como ajustarlo, y en cuanto a la tabla intente colocarle el ciclo for que me proporcionaste y no tuve exito, voy a editar la pregunta porque lo que estoy haciendo es tomar los valores de una base de datos y sigue quedandose corta la ventana T_T espero me puedas ayudar nuevamente

Comment: @JohnnyLs el como llenas el tree es irrelevante realmente, tu problema está en que tienes seguramente mal estructurado tab2 (grid) o tu notebook (no se adapta al tamaño de la venta, por ejemplo por usar place para posicionarlo en la ventana principal de forma absoluta). Eso si la scrollbar añádela en el inicializador o dónde creas el tree, no en la función que lo llena.

Comment: Intenta añadir un [mcve] que permita reproducir el problema, incluye la creación de tab2 y la de todos los widgets que contiene y la creación de su padre, el notebook, y cómo posicionas éste en la ventana principal. Tu problema está en alguno de estos pasos, alguno de los widgets no se está adaptando dinámicamente al tamaño del padre.

Comment: FJSevilla una disculpa por responder apenas, ayer estuve lleno de cosas y apenas pude ver tu respuesta, gracias amigo por tomarte el tiempo de responder, yo estaba necio a que en la forma de llenar la tabla desde la base de datos se encontraba el problema, como comentas el problema puede estar en la ventana o en la Notebook, de hecho intentare hacer la recomendacion porque no he visto donde tengo el problema T_T en cuanto tenga la respuesta voy a postearla para que otros usuarios puedan verla

Comment: FJSevilla, amigo, encontré el error despues de ver mucho tiempo el codigo me di cuenta que el problema radicaba en la altura de la tabla, por eso los datos se seguian de largo entonces arregle modificando la altura segun la siguiente linea:  self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.frame1, show='headings', height=15, columns=columns) en vez de 30 que lo tenia asi, lo deje en 15 y zaz funcionó!!!! nuevamente agradezco tus comentarios y sobretodo el tiempo para hacer miniprogramas de ejemplo

Comment: FJSevilla, disculpa que reviva este post, intenté añadir un scrollbar horizontal donde hay 19 columnas donde no se ven todas, sino me equivoco el codigo para plantearlo es: `vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.tab3, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree2.xview); vsb.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W +E); self.tree2.configure(xscrollcommand = vsb.set)` , pero solo aparece el widget y no la barra de desplazamiento, vi tu comment en el post **¿Cómo hago para crear un scrollbar?** hablas de que es mas dificil hacer un scrollbar horizontal?  alguna sugerencia para poder configurarlo??? disculpa y gracias!

Comment: @JohnnyLs en este caso el proceso es similar al de la barra vertical, solo asegúrate de que la scroll ocupa las mismas columnas que el tree. He editado la respuesta y creado otro ejemplo usando también una scroll horizontal mira a ver si te orienta.

Comment: gracias por tu comment, de hecho estuve reproduciendo el ejemplo en otro *.py y funcionó pero al quererlo reproducir en mi programa principal me sigue dando el mismo problema, seguí modificando a lo cual se logró pero mi tabla se ve super pequeña y no he encontrado la manera de expandirla, crees que me puedas orientar un poco mas? ya que casi estoy cerca de ajustarlo pero ya no se me da la cabeza para encontrar la solucion, voy a editar mi pregunta dejabdo mas abajo el codigo que tengo hasta ahora